# Punctuation error in Improve Post error message

Tags: bug, status-declined, error-message, grammar, improve-edit

In the Suggested Edits review queue, if you select **Improve** and then immediately press save (without making any improvements), this error message appears:

> You seem to be improving a post however, you made no changes.

There is a punctuation error. Also, "You seem to be" is unnecessarily verbose, since the software knows for sure that you are improving a post. It should instead be something like

> Improving a post requires making changes.
>
> When improving a post, you must make changes.

Comment: Watch out, Jeff might come to your house and bludgeon you with a giant comma.

Comment: @SimpleCoder: Do you mean with `❜` U+275C HEAVY SINGLE COMMA QUOTATION MARK ORNAMENT?

Comment: \*gasp\* That's a thing? Be on the lookout.

Comment: For the uninitiated: [Jeff Atwood's Big-S](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/63791#63791) (Pluralization Bug, from [The Many Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478))